# Adding events from sheets to google calendar

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm brand new to coding anything to get things to function just a little easier (this isn't even my code).

I've copied the code below that I'm using (and it works!!!). Unfortunately, I have two columns of information that I want to use as my description in google calendar but its kind of messy where either one column is filled or both and when I run the code, it puts just one column of information in leaving some information blank which isn't helpful when im looking at my calendar for what needs to be done by end of day.

```
function addEventsToCalendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var rawEvents = spreadsheet.getRange(dataRange).getValues();
  var events = rawEvents.filter(function(r){
    return r.join("").length > 0;
  });

  deleteAutoCreatedEvents();
  
  for (var event of events) {
    
    var date = event[0];
    var name = event[1];
    var description = event[2||3];
```

I've tried to throw different symbols in (the OR function is the most recent one). I've looked on here for some solutions too, adding lines such as activeCell.getColumn() and filling with my values  but had no idea how to define what needed to be filled (this solution also resulted in an error code saying "event is not a function")

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete.  Also `dataRange` and `deleteAutoCreatedEvents` are undefined.